# Windows 10 Groove music default app can't show songs bitrate?

Tags: windows-10, audio, mp3, bitrate, groove-music

I opened some mp3s on Windows 10 and Groove Music is launched as default app to reproduce them... Well, I was looking to have songs bitrate shown in current playlist (together with song title, duration, etc...) or maybe somewhere to look at properties of the current playing song or one of the other in the list, staying inside Groove app of course, but I really can't find anything to make it show... is it me missing something or is it Groove app just don't support showing that information?

Answer (score 0):

After Reddy Lutonadio's (whom I thank for the help) answer, I'm almost convinced that, at the time I'm writing, Groove Music app really doesn't provide the possibility to show/know my audio file's bitrate.

So, by now, if I want to know the audio file bitrate I must go on right-clicking on it (in Windows file explorer) > Properties > Details.

Or simply go with a different music player, like (for instance) [Winyl](https://winyl-player.github.io/), [DeaDBeeF](https://deadbeef.sourceforge.io/), [Audacious](https://audacious-media-player.org/) or [Quod Libet](https://quodlibet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (just not to mention Clementine, Strawberry, and many others...)

P.S.
I like Winyl the most 'cause, just like Groove Music, it has a "out-of-the-box" crossfade effect when you pass from a song to another or when you pause/resume or stop a song plus it let's you filter/search music and that's absolutely needed when you have a HUGE library to rummage in, looking for "that mood song"...

P.P.S.
For completeness I must say Audacious is also great imho and has the crossfading feature as well that can be activated if you wish, just look for it among plugin effects. Having the possibility to choose whether to activate it or not is for sure a MUST for a music lover as some albums (like for instance one of Pink Floyd's masterpiece, The Dark Side Of The Moon) get "ruined" by an "always-on" crossfade effect.